# Localize WinForms which will used from 3-party application

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2017

We have created a Class-Library project with some WinForms inside.
We translated the Forms via build in VS designer (set Localizable=true).

VS will create the assembly and the different folders for each language with containing satellite resource files.

This assembly will be loaded by an 3-party application.

Now we have the issue, that our Forms won't get localized if we start it via the 3-party application.
It seems, that our assembly isn't able to load the resource files from the language sub-directories.

Is it possible to load this resource file by code, so the default localize-mechanism of the WinForms will work?

**Edit**

If i copy the language folders (de, en, ...) to the main 3-party app folder, everything will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the localization works depending on the thread culture. Are you sure, that the third-party application sets the right culture on startup?

```
// set culture on program startup
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture       = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture     = ci;

// .NET 4.5 and above
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture   = ci;
```

From MSDN:

*"In the .NET Framework 4 and previous versions, by default, the UI culture of all threads is set to the Windows system culture. For applications whose current UI culture differs from the default system culture, this behavior is often undesirable. In the .NET Framework 4.5, the DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture property lets you define the default UI culture of all threads in an application domain."*

So, if you are using .NET 3.5, the cultures of the thread-pool and worker threads may also differ from your wanted application culture, if that is different from the OS culture. You should check/set the culture on each threaded call, if that is required.

Comment: I tried this already, but it seems not to be the problem.
I tested creating an Resource file and use the auto generated ResourceManager with `ResourceManager.GetString()` and supplying different CultureInfos, but no success.

So i think, my assembly isn't able to automatically locate the satellite resource files and load it.

Comment: @Markus: I use that WinForms localization feature, starting with .NET 1.0, without such a problem. Do you have the satellite assemblies in your applications target directory? E.g. MyForms.dll in parallel to the MyApp.exe and the German MyForms.resources.dll in the "de" subdirectory?

Comment: Yes.
I think the issue is, that the 3-party app load my assembly and my now executing assembly can't find the satellite resources.

If i copy the language folders (de, en,...) with the containing resources files to the main folder of the 3-party app, it will work like a charm.

So i need to load the resource manually via code, but i don't know how.

Comment: @Markus: Did you check, which exact UI culture is set on the UI thread (e.g. de-DE)? And if that matches with the localized DLL, e.g. de? Maybe, you can add a TRACE output into a logfile or a temporary message box with that information.

Comment: I edit my question:
If i copy the resource folders/files to the main folder of 3-party app, everything will work like a charm.
So i need a way to load these resources into my assembly via code in a way, the build in localization mechanisms will work. But i don't know how

Comment: @Markus: That is, how the .NET localization works. Copy all satellite assemblies to the corresponding language-dependent subdirectories, e.g. during a post-build step in Visual Studio or during installation. By setting the culture of the UI thread, the .NET runtime is instructed to search for the corresponding satellite assemblies in the target directory. There is no need for manual loading.